# Logstash parse log using JSON filter

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash

This is our application log format and I'm trying to process the same using the filter block(json) of logstash.

```
{"asctime": "2023-07-26 09:05:08,271", "levelname": "INFO", "pathname": "/app/realtime_processor/parallel_processor.py", "lineno": 280, "message": "comment_body: **SonarQube Quality Gate**\n\n[![Quality Gate passed](https://... does not match defined phrase: rerun ingress-garuda-prod", "namespace": "challenger-rover", "version": "jfrog.artifactory:5060/drpbuilds/list-groovy-real:583eb6a", "pod": "ingress-garuda-prod-647c5d755-7jmwx"}
```

however I'm not sure what should be the source field here, as it's a required field and none of the field have JSON data.

How should I handle this ? thanks.

logstash config

```
input {
  http {
    port => 9200
  }
}

filter {
    json {
       source => "message"
       remove_field => ["message"]
    }
    mutate {
      remove_field => [ "_index", "_score" ]
    }
}
```